# Submitting forms in background

Tags: ajax, forms, post, prototypejs

I want a user to submit multiple form at once by submitting a "master" form.

I got it working by using mootools' "send" function, but we switched to prototype and I can't get the same result.
using "submit" just "clicks" all forms.

basicly what I need: A function to submit all form by just using an Ajax POST call. Strangely all ajax functions I tested didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, Form.request did the job